# How to add a custom type in typescript which extends a basic type with some conditions

Tags: typescript, casting, typescript-typings

So I'm planning to make a custom type by the name `address` which is basically a string with certain limitations, like it should start with `0x` and should be of a fixed length size.

```
// valid
let aliceAddress: address = '0x7A58df2c58c92e7de350da05052Af1F56331453b'

// But this one should throw an error
let bobAddress: address = 'New York, NY, US'
```

Now previously I tried branded types and just using string type (both of which don't seem to fit in my case). Is there a way in which I can extend string and some custom conditions to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good question and for now it's impossible to create type with a RegExp or complexe structure with a string. I tried this to test :

```js
type part =
    | '0'
    | '1'
    | '2'
    | '3'
    | '4'
    | '5'
    | '6'
    | '7'
    | '8'
    | '9'
    | 'a'
    | 'b'
    | 'c'
    | 'd'
    | 'e'
    | 'f'
    | 'g'
    | 'h'
    | 'i'
    | 'j'
    | 'k'
    | 'l'
    | 'm'
    | 'n'
    | 'o'
    | 'p'
    | 'q'
    | 'r'
    | 's'
    | 't'
    | 'u'
    | 'v'
    | 'w'
    | 'x'
    | 'y'
    | 'z'
    | 'A'
    | 'B'
    | 'C'
    | 'D'
    | 'E'
    | 'F'
    | 'G'
    | 'H'
    | 'I'
    | 'J'
    | 'K'
    | 'L'
    | 'M'
    | 'N'
    | 'O'
    | 'P'
    | 'Q'
    | 'R'
    | 'S'
    | 'T'
    | 'U'
    | 'V'
    | 'W'
    | 'X'
    | 'Y'
    | 'Z'
// There is an error because the created type is too complexe.
export type address = `0x${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}${part}`
// Can just do something like this to match beginning pattern but don't have the length
export type address2 = `0x${string}`
```

After that you can use the [Typescript Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to have a specified type to resolve your problem like this :

```
export type address = `0x${string}`

function isAddress(adrs: address | string): adrs is address {
    return /^0x[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}$/g.test(adrs)
}

if(isAddress(anything)) {
    // ... your code here with the var anything is type address
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think I would be needing a regex it seems.